# How to get SSRS Report server database "TABLE" details?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Working on SQL Server Monitoring Product and want to add SSRS monitoring capabilities in this.
When i try to search on web description/details of Report server Database i.e. `ReportServer${InstanceName}` and `ReportServer${InstanceName}TempDB`

But there is no description/details found on it.
But rather i found on Microsoft Forum as 
"writing queries against the SSRS DB is not supported and the schema, content, interpretation of the content is subject to change without notice." on [This](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlreportingservices/thread/60dd3392-42d8-4dc4-b8e6-15e9aeaad29e) Link comment of Lukasz

I only concern is it true that Microsoft don't provide this Info.
Why Microsoft dont provide this info even though we are paying lot of amount for this product?

am i suppose to drill down each and every table in above both the DBs and apply my logic to find monitoring attributes?

If you know any other ways to get this details it will really helpful.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: As much as I sympathise with you, this question would be better directed at Lukasz or someone at Microsoft, rather than SO.

Comment: @MarkBannister Yes you are right :) but SO is site where i can get genuine answers ;P +1 for your sympathies.

Answer (score 2):

The best resource I know to get started with admin scripts that run against the ReportServer db can be found here: http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/42440a6b-c5b1-4acc-9632-d608d1c40a5c

With some tweaking, it could help you out.